# Google Maps Static API request isn't working over https

Tags: api, google-maps, https, google-maps-static-api

I have a simple webpage (local) served over https which should display an image created via the [Google Maps Static API](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/maps-static/overview). If I try to create the map image by making a request to the API via http like this:

`<img src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/staticmap?center=51.928980,4.462400&zoom=14&size=400x300&key=MY_API_KEY&signature=MY_SIGNATURE" />`

Everything works fine, except I get a 'Mixed content' warning in the console as could be expected.

However if I try to request the image over https like this:

`<img src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/staticmap?center=51.928980,4.462400&zoom=14&size=400x300&key=MY_API_KEY&signature=MY_SIGNATURE" />`

I get a 403 error and the image is not loaded. If I just copy the `src` of the above `img` element and open it in a new browser tab, I get the image without any problems.

Can anybody tell me what might be going wrong here?

Comment: Your request works without problem for me with my own API key. Check out this [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/fn3tms85/) and replace `YOUR_API_KEY` with your own key. Does it show up? If it doesn't then the problem is with your API key. Try [unrestricting](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/maps-static/get-api-key) it completely and/or generating a brand new API key. If it's still not working, it may be a server or network related issue and I'd suggest contacting Google Maps Tech Support.

Comment: The same problem I'm afraid. I'n my case I also require the usage of a signature. So the map will not be loaded anyway. But when I try via `https` in your fiddle nothing is loaded at all (403 error). And if I try via `http` the map is loaded but it will give Google's error message that a signature is required.

Comment: I see, then I really suggest you contact Tech Support right away https://developers.google.com/maps/support#contact-maps-support